# How to fix bad dd img write to sdcard

Tags: image, macos, raspberry-pi, sd-card, dd

I am trying to write `2016-05-10-raspbian-jessie.img` (an image) to my SanDisk Ultra 4GB (Class? 4) SDCARD using my MacBook Pro (running OS X) for my Raspberry Pi.

When I run the dd cmd it gives some errors:

```
Matts-MacBook-Pro:dev Matt$ sudo dd bs=1m if=~/Downloads/2016-05-10-raspbian-jessie.img of=/dev/rdisk2
dd: /dev/rdisk2: short write on character device
dd: /dev/rdisk2: Input/output error
3782+0 records in
3781+1 records out
3965190144 bytes transferred in 635.507654 secs (6239406 bytes/sec)
```

I actually get the files on the SDcard but when I boot the Raspberry Pi, I get a kernel panic:

```
Unable to mount root filessystem on unknown block
```

[An old forum post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=12245&start=25) recommends:

- adding a `forcefsck` to the end of `cmdline.txt` on the SDCard.
- using fsck: `sudo fsck -fy /dev/disk2`, but I just get back the usage text: `usage: fsck -fdnypq -l number`

What is the best way to do this in OS X? My MBP is my only working SDCard reader, I can't get the commands that "should" work to work in fsck. It'd even better if you know what the cause is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How big is the image file, and what's the actual size of the SD card? That looks like it might have run out of space on the disk, since "3965190144 bytes transferred" is 3.965 GB, which is pretty close to the nominal 4GB capacity of the card.

Note: when checking sizes there's a potential for confusion between true gigabytes (GB = 1,000,000,000 bytes) and gibibytes (GiB = 1,073,741,824 bytes) which are sometimes *called* gigabytes. Disk sizes are generally given in true GB, but RAM is generally given in GiB, and software tools for showing sizes are often inconsistent. When in doubt, look at the actual number of bytes. In OS X, you can get the exact disk size with e.g. `diskutil info /dev/disk2`.

Comment: diskutil info /dev/disk2 ->
Total Size:4.0 GB (3965190144 Bytes) (exactly 7744512 512-Byte-Units)
Mounting the img as disk3

Comment: Mounting the img as disk3
   Total Size: 4.0 GB (4016046080 Bytes) (exactly 7843840 512-Byte-Units)
Yeah it's too big. How do I trim an image that doesn't actually use all it's allotted space?

Comment: Formatting the SDCard with [SDFormatter|https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/] and copying the files out of a mounted img on to it gives the same error in the RPi. Maybe I need to 'fix' the sdcard after a bad write? Is fsck not the tool?

Comment: @ConfigurationNation I don't know how to do this on OS X -- there's a script [here](http://sirlagz.net/2013/03/10/script-automatic-rpi-image-downsizer/) to shrink images, but it uses Linux tools that aren't available on OS X. Do you have (another) Linux box around you could do it on?

Comment: Thanks Gordon I didn't have to re-partition (I don't think) the image had unused space and I managed to shrink my image down on OSX by installing coreutils ('brew install coreutils') which contains gtruncate.
unmounting the img with diskutils umount and then gtruncate --size=7744512.
The dd command then worked without errors!
fdisk mysdcard still shows a couple of empty partitions as the img did.

Comment: *Unfortunately* when I plug it in to my RPi I still get the kernel panic :( and fsck still doesn't seem to want to run on the sdcard.